# How to group depending on values in Crystal Reports?

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a bunch of data about people attended or unattended, and I want to sepparate them. In one column I have '0' for unattended people, and some number for the attended ones. How can I show that in a report? I want a pie chart that divides them, and I've spent many hours in this, I don't even know how to search about it and I have almost no experience with Crystal Reports.

I've tried making two summarize formulas for acumulated totals like this (the other one looks almost the same):

```
StrCmp(ToText({table.Atendido}),"0") <> 0
```

But I can't use that in a pie chart. And it doesn't even stores the data as it supposed to do, in my data I have 8 unattended, 1 attended. This formula gives me 9 as result.

Any help is greatly apreciated, thanks!

My data looks like this:

```
IDPerson   Person   Attended
1          John     0
2          Mary     0
3          Graves   1
4          Paula    0
```

In the report I need:

- Who was attended (list of people)
- A pie chart of attended, unattended with percentages and all

If I group by Attended, the groups form like this:

[image: Bad groups]

There will be many groups of numbers > 0, I just need groups sepparated by:

- attended = 0
- attended != 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was over complicating it, because I'm inexperienced and in a hurry...

I made a formula to separate both values:

```
if tonumber({PacientesAtendidosYNoAtendidos.Atendido}) = 0 then 0 else 1
```

Then, I just grouped by that. Very silly, indeed.

[image: Yep]

Answer (score 0):

I hope i understand your question but if you group on Attended then you should be able to get what you want with count functions.

Comment: Thanks for your response! this is the result: http://i.imgur.com/Of8uuU6.png?1 but this is NOT what I need, I need two groups, in the way you are telling me there will be a bunch of groups by numbers > 0 and the one group of numbers = 0.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding you but i thought attended had two values 1 or 0. If that's true then you should have two groups that you can count or get a distinct count one. if I'm misunderstanding you post a snapshot of your report design view